# How does numpy argmax work?

Tags: python, numpy

So I know that the numpy argmax retrieves the maximum value along an axis. Thus,

```
x = np.array([[12,11,10,9],[16,15,14,13],[20,19,18,17]])
print(x)
print(x.sum(axis=1))
print(x.sum(axis=0))
```

would output,

```
[[12 11 10  9]
 [16 15 14 13]
 [20 19 18 17]]


[42 58 74]

[48 45 42 39]
```

This makes sense as the sum along axis 1 (row) is `[42 58 74]` and axis 0 (column) is `[48 45 42 39]`.
However, i am confused of how argmax work. From my understanding, argmax is supposed to return the max number along the axis. Below is my code and output.

Code: `print(np.argmax(x,axis=1))`. Output: `[0 0 0]`

Code: `print(np.argmax(x,axis=0))`. Output: `[2 2 2 2]`

Where does `0` and `2` come from? I've deliberately used a set of more complex integer values (9..20) so as to distinguish between the `0` and `2` and the integer values inside the array.

Comment: may i know why it was downvoted

Comment: what do u mean by index of maximum value

Comment: i googled for it and yet i dont understand. I even tried coding it out to understand how it works. Do u think i will go through the trouble of posting a long post and trying it out without googling?

Comment: `np.max` returns the maximum values along the respective axis; `np.argmax` returns 'where' those values occur, the `index`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.argmax(x,axis=1)` returns the *index* of maximum of in every row.

`axis=1` means "along axis 1", i.e, row.

```
[[12 11 10  9]    <-- max at index 0
 [16 15 14 13]    <-- max at index 0
 [20 19 18 17]]   <-- max at index 0
```

Thus its output is `[0 0 0]`.

It's similar for `np.argmax(x,axis=0)`, but now it returns the *index* of maximum of in every column.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It's good to see people replying in kind unlike how the OP was initially down-voted and rebuked by another user.

Answer (score 0):

Correction:
`axis=0` refers to rows, not to columns.
`axis=1` refers to columns, not to rows.

```
x = np.array([[12,11,10,9],[16,15,14,13],[20,19,18,17]])
  print(x)

[[12 11 10  9]
[16 15 14 13]
[20 19 18 17]]

np.argmax(x, axis=0)
array([2, 2, 2, 2] # third row, index 2 of each of the 4 columns

np.argmax(x, axis=1)
array([0, 0, 0]  # first column, index 0 of each of the three rows.
```